# jQuery, undefined function if used in a different function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm writing a **jQuery plugin**, which similar to this,

```
$(this).each(function(){
    $el = $(this).find('.el')
    $el.click(function(){
       test();
    });
    function test() {
       console.log('test init');
    }
});
```

This works fine when `$el` is clicked

but when i use the `test()` outside of `$el.click` like this

```
$(this).each(function(){
    $el = $(this).find('.el')
    test();
    function test() {
       console.log('test init');
    }
});
```

I get type error `undefined is not a function`

PS: I'm coding in coffee, syntax/spelling isn't an issue here

Comment: because... `test()` isn't defined yet when it is called? JS executes lineraly, which is like "top-to-bottom". try moving test below the declaration, and tell me if it works.

Comment: i see, thanks so what would be the best way to keep the function below the whole code, but still activate it? Becuase it will look kind of ugly to bring a chunk of function on the top.

Comment: Exactly test is not defined yet and when you set .click event binding it works fine; also if I may ask why are you keeping the function definition inside the .each loop? just curious! hope this helps, cheers

Comment: ah, yeah, i got little carried away in coding with coffee, the indentation wasn't right, and by the time I found out, and put it out the loop, all functions becomes undefined. and since it was already 200 lines, i just kept going until this roadblock. thanks to Joseph for the solution, i definetly going to optimise the whole script afterwards.

Comment: [The code you posted is fine](http://jsfiddle.net/c7XWa/). Function declarations are "hoisted" to the top of the enclosing scope. @Joseph: You are not correct, see this comment.

Comment: @FelixKling it was a blind guess, hence the question mark and *"and tell me if it works"* part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your `test()` needs to execute immediately, then do this:

```
$(this).each(function(){
    $el = $(this).find('.el')

    (function test() {
       console.log('test init');
    }());                          //the "()" at the end executes the function
});
```

but `test()` [won't be available from the outside world](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9835527/575527) this way. it's somewhat "enclosed". if you need test to execute immediately *and still be callable by others*, do this:

```
$(this).each(function(){
    $el = $(this).find('.el')

    var test = (function testFunc() {
       console.log('test init');
       return testFunc;                //return itself to the variable "test"
    }());                              //execute
});
```

Comment: For the last case you could also go `var test = function() {[...]}; test();`.

Comment: @dbaupp i considered that, but it would "look cleaner" if you had an immediately-invoked expression that was at the same time a declaration.